# JSONP Receive back non-parseable JSON

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jsonp

Receiving back Non-Parseable JSON Response. I receive back the JSON fine but it's in this exact format, how do I parse and say alert all containing values per row. Many thanks in advance!

request start

```
$.ajax({
    url: apiURL+'getLocations/category/'+ category +'/countyId/'+ countyId +'/searchString/'+ searchString +'?callback=?',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    callback: callTest1(),
    complete: function(data){
        if(data.code != '400')
        {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $.each(value, function(key, val){
                    alert(data.id);
                })
            });
        }
    },
    success: callTest2()
});
```

request end

output start

```
{"Location":[{"id":0,"postcodeId":85,"categoryId":0,"location":
    "Enfield Island Village"},{"id":0,"postcodeId":44,"categoryId":0,
    "location":"Isle of Dogs"},{"id":0,"postcodeId":269,"categoryId":0,
    "location":"Isleworth"},{"id":0,"postcodeId":135,"categoryId":0,
    "location":"Islington"}]
}
```

output end

Comment: In what way is this non-parsable?

Comment: Well, I cannot find a way to read out the data inside the output JSON, any suggestions? I am new to this so apology for the ignorance... thanks for your patience

Comment: An output example would be very appreciated

Comment: What happens if you set `dataType` to `json` instead of `jsonp`?  The docs say that `jsonp` will add the callback parameter to the URL directly.  Since you already have one there, presumably you're stomping on each other.

Comment: I know what you are suggesting exactly CDHOWIE but same response JSON is received. I am running a good console trace and I also receive back "invalid label" and prints out a portion of the JSON I.E.: "invalid label" {"Location":[{"id":0,"postcodeId":199,...":0,"location":"Abbey Wood"},{"id":0,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var data = {"Location":[{"id":0,"postcodeId":85,"categoryId":0,"location":
    "Enfield Island Village"},{"id":0,"postcodeId":44,"categoryId":0,
    "location":"Isle of Dogs"},{"id":0,"postcodeId":269,"categoryId":0,
    "location":"Isleworth"},{"id":0,"postcodeId":135,"categoryId":0,
    "location":"Islington"}]
};

$.each(data.Location, function(index, val){
    alert(val.id + " , " + val.postcodeId + " , " +val.categoryId + " , " +val.location );
});
```

I think that you are missing the `.Location` part.

If you are not comfortable with hard coded values, try this.

```
$.each(data.Location, function(index, datum) {
    $.each(datum, function(key, value) {
        alert(key + " : " + value.toString());
    });
});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/kLEA6/